# is it possible to use ES6 template literals instead of view engines for express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, backend

I'm getting started with back-end web development using Node and Express and i have seen a tutorial using view engines to render websites as a server response..and a question got to my mind could i use the template literals to do the same functionality?

in the front-end i used to use handlebars but i ditched it just started using those literals as they do exactly the same functionality..cloud it be the same case with the back-end too? and how?

could i create a js file the contains the template and set it to the view engine directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`res.send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send)

> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an
> Array. For example:

```js
res.send(Buffer.from('whoop'))
res.send({ some: 'json' })
res.send('<p>some html</p>')
res.status(404).send('Sorry, we cannot find that!')
res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' })
```

i.e:

```js
const html = `
<html>
  <head>
    <title>overrides</title>
  </head>
  </body>
    <div>test</div>
  </body>
</html>
`
app.get('/test', (req,res) => {
  res.send(html)
});
```

This will output:

[image]

And you can use `module.exports` to export code chunks.